# Scraping second page of dynamic element on webpage with Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I work for a group that's looking to pull automatic reports of port statuses in Tx. To do this, I'm trying to web scrape (which I'm not too familiar with) the Coast Guard Homeport site. I've managed to use Selenium to pull all the information using the xpath of the page's table with the ports, however there is one port (Victoria) on the 'page 2' of the table that the script is not able to see. The xpath does not change if I tab between the pages, so I'm not sure how to locate it. Any help would be much appreciated!

**edit: The page uses Javascript elements.**

https://homeport.uscg.mil/port-directory/corpus-christi

```
    url = 'https://homeport.uscg.mil/port-directory/corpus-christi'
    xpath= "/html/body/form/div[12]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/table"
    portsList = ['CORPUS CHRISTI','ORANGE','BEAUMONT','VICTORIA','CALHOUN','HARLINGEN','PALACIOS','PORT ISABEL','PORT LAVACA','PORT MANSFIELD']
                        
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=portsList, columns=['status','comments','dateupdated'])
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"C:\Users\M3ECHJJJ\Documents\chromedriver.exe")
    urlpage = url+page
    driver.get(urlpage)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
    time.sleep(15)
    results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
    ports_split = results[0].text.split('\n')
    i = 0
    for port in ports_split:
         if port.upper() in portsList:
                print(port)
                df.xs(port.upper())['status'],df.xs(port.upper())['comments'],df.xs(port.upper())['dateupdated'] = parsePara(ports_split[i+1])
         i = i+1
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Long story short: Replicate whatever is being done to change the tab/page. You could also attempt to reverse-engineer the requests that the pages is making, in order to get the data in a more direct/efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

First, be very careful writing automation that acts against government websites (or any website for that matter) and be sure you're allowed to do so. You may also find that many sites offer the information you're looking for in a structured format, like through an API or data download.

While `selenium` may provide you with a great tool for automating the browser, its capabilities for locating elements and parsing HTML may leave much to be desired. In cases like this, I might reach for using `BeautifulSoup` as a complementary tool to use alongside browser automation.

BeautifulSoup will support all the same locators as selenium, but also provides additional capabilities, including the ability to define your own criteria for locating elements.

For example, you can define a function to use very specific rules for locating elements (tags). The function should return `True` for tags that match your interests.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def important_table(tag):
    """Given a particular tag, return True if it's what you're looking for"""
    return bool(
            # match <table> elements
            tag.name == 'table' and  
            # check for expected text
            any(port_name in tag.text for port_name in portsList) and 
            # check element attributes
            "classname" in tag.get('class', []) and
            # has at least 3 rows
            len(tag.findall('tr')) > 3  
            # and so on
             )
```

This is just an example, but you can write this function however you like to fit your need.

Then you could apply this like so

```py
...
    driver.get(urlpage)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
    time.sleep(15)
    html = driver.page_source  # get the DOM content as a string
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    table = soup.find(important_table)
    for row in table.findall('tr'):
        print(row.text)
```

Comment: _While selenium may provide you with a great tool for automating the browser, its capabilities for locating elements and parsing HTML may leave much to be desired. In cases like this, I might reach for using BeautifulSoup as a complementary tool to use alongside browser automation._ I find that a bit surprising, is it that Selenium can't do what BS does, or is it a matter of simplicity?

Comment: In principle, a few caveats aside, you could do almost the same things with selenium by iterating over every single element (for example `find_elements_by_xpath` with an xpath that matches every element) then filtering the elements accordingly. However, BS still offers more capabilities that selenium does not have when interacting with/parsing  the element objects, particularly with regard to relationship between elements. It also has all the functionality out-of-the-box. So it's not so much that selenium _cant_ so much as it _doesn't_.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but permissions isn't an issue here. I neglected to mention I think the table uses Javascript and not HTML. Does BeautifulSoup still offer more capabilities there?